# JHipster - None of the configured nodes are available Jhipster 5.x ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster

I can't insert an instance of my entity AvisRendezVous inside the database. When I click on save, I got the following error from the server :

```
exception = 'None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1
}{C6hOYYyORMy7Kbms4pck3g}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]'
```

[image: Internal server error image]

On the JHipster documentation they said we need to start elasticsearch instance with `docker-compose`, so I did that :

[image: Docker-compose image]

Here is my elasticsearch.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
    apspg_elastic-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:5.6.5
        # volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/APSPG_Elastic/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
        command: -Enetwork.host=0.0.0.0 -Ediscovery.type=single-node
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you access elasticsearch in the browser at localhost:9200?

Comment: @JonRuddell Thanks for your answer. No I can't access ! I guess my docker-compose is not working

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7810